# My max-min value of array code not working

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, max, min

I had this code perfect but once I started to fix it up a little, it started giving me errors I didn't understand how to fix. Help?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MinMax
{
public class Exercise
{

    public int Min(int[] numbers)
    {
        int m = numbers[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (m > numbers[i])
            {
                m = numbers[i];
                return m;
            }
        }

    }

    public int Max(int[] numbers)
    {
        int m = numbers[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (m < numbers[i])
            {
                m = numbers[i];
                return m;
            }
        }
    }

    public static int Main()
    {
        int [] nbrs = new int[10];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int x = 0;
        foreach (int i in nbrs)
        {
            int gen = rnd.Next(1, 501);
            nbrs [x] = gen;
            Console.WriteLine(nbrs [x] + ", ");
            x++;
        };

        Exercise exo = new Exercise();
        Console.WriteLine("The minimum of the array is {0}", exo.Min(nbrs));
        Console.WriteLine("The maximum of the array is {0}", exo.Max(nbrs));
        return 0;
    }
}}
```

The errors 'prog.cs(11,20): error CS0161: `MinMax.Exercise.Min(int[])': not all code paths return a value' and 'prog.cs(25,20): error CS0161:`MinMax.Exercise.Max(int[])': not all code paths return a value' came up but I don't understand how since it was working just fine.

Comment: You return the fist value which greater than first element of array.

Comment: You need to return a value if the maximum or minimum are not found.

Comment: The return-statement inside the for loop may end the loop prematurely. Place it after the for loop!

Comment: not only that part is the problem. `foreach (int i in nbrs)` nbrs is array of ints. you want to set the array then use for loop. not foreach. currently `i` is useless and also you used a counter anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Update part of your code like this:

```
public int Min(int[] numbers)
{
    int m = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        if (m > numbers[i])
        {
            m = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    return m;
}

public int Max(int[] numbers)
{
    int m = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        if (m < numbers[i])
        {
            m = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

EDIT: This will help you get rid of the error you are getting. But you still need to figure out the logic on returning the correct value.

**The reason you were getting this error is because, if in case none of the numbers in the array `int[] numbers` that you are passing to the methods satisfy the if condition `if (m > numbers[i])`, the code would never reach the return statement.**

Comment: Please, *please* add an explanation and not just the code. You aren't helping *anyone* by just doing this guys homework for him.

Comment: Why starting to loop at index 0? `numbers[0]` has already been assigned to `m`?

Answer (score 1):

Ive commented out the wrong parts with some explanations, hope it helps.

```
public class Exercise
{

    public static int Min(int[] numbers)
    {
        int m = numbers[0];

        // Start at index 1, not 0. m can never be greater than numbers[0].
        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (m > numbers[i])
            {
                m = numbers[i];

                //return m; // This returns at the first number smaller than numbers[0].
            }
        }
        return m; // return the final result here. `if` statement may never get executed.
        //but the method must return `m` anyway as a result
    }

    public static int Max(int[] numbers)
    {
        int m = numbers[0];

        // Start at index 1, not 0. m can never be less than numbers[0].
        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (m < numbers[i])
            {
                m = numbers[i];
                //return m; // This returns at the first number larger than numbers[0].
            }
        }
        return m; // return the final result here. `if` statement may never get executed.
        //but the method must return `m` anyway as a result
    }

    public static void Main() // Main method should not return value
    {
        int[] nbrs = new int[10];
        Random rnd = new Random();

        // dont use `foreach` on array when you want to set values to that array.
        // also `for` has a counter itself. remove the x and put it in `for` statement.
        for (int x = 0; x < nbrs.Length; x++)
        {
            int gen = rnd.Next(1, 501);
            nbrs[x] = gen;
            Console.WriteLine(nbrs[x] + ", ");
        }


        //Exercise exo = new Exercise();
        // you dont have to create a new instance of the current class.
        // just use the methods directly but make them static in order to access it.
        Console.WriteLine("The minimum of the array is {0}", Min(nbrs));
        Console.WriteLine("The maximum of the array is {0}", Max(nbrs));
    }
}
```